# Sequelize Self Relationship with junction table

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I want to build a sequelize relationship that represents : `An item is composed by a specific amount of others items`.

*Database tables*

```
Item (itemId, name)
Ingredient (ingredientId, itemParentId, itemChildrenId, amount)
```

*Sequelize models*

```
// Item.js
class Item extends Sequelize.Model { }
Item.init({
  itemId: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true
  },
  name: Sequelize.STRING,
}, {
  sequelize: db,
})

// Ingredient.js
class Ingredient extends Sequelize.Model { }
Ingredient.init({
  ingredientId: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true
  },
  amount: Sequelize.INTEGER,
}, {
  sequelize: db,
})
```

And I am just trying to write the correct sequelize association to match my database logic, so I tried :

```
// Association.js
Item.belongsToMany(Item, { through: Ingredient, as: 'ingredients', foreignKey: 'itemParentId' })
```

But I'm having this error `Unknown column 'ingredients->ingredient.ingredientItemId' in 'field list'`, which is true but I do not know how to specify the right keys/columns.

Any help, please!

Answer (score 0):

I see few problems: First, you're performing Item.init within the Ingredient model. Probably a mistake on your part. Change it to Ingredient.init.(personally i never used this "init" api, i define models differently, so i'm not sure how it works)

Second, change the primary keys of both Ingredient and Item to be just "id", like:

```
id: {
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    autoIncrement: true,
    primaryKey: true
  }
```

Also, your association isn't correct, it needs to be through a junction table:

```
Item.belongsToMany(Ingredient, { through: "ItemIngredient"})
```

Note that "through" referes here to a table name, that Sequelize will create automatically if you're using model.sync(), and if not- you will need to create it yourself(or with a migration, which i recommend), with columns: itemId, ingredientId.

You also need to add the "reverse" association, like that:

```
Ingredient.belongsToMany(Item, { through: "ItemIngredient"})
```

Comment: For the Item.init 2 times, was just a copy mistake, I just edited it. And I am not sure you understood the problem, I do not need a table ItemIngredient as Ingredient is the junction table between Item and itself.

Comment: I solved my problem without using `through` but using `Item.hasMany(Ingredient, { ... })` two times with different keys (`itemParentId` and `itemChildrenId`).

Comment: Ah so it's not many-to-many, seems to be more like one-to-many